# What answer format is better? short and concise or long and descriptive

Tags: discussion, answers

Short and concise may lead to not being thorough, but a longer answer might risk being tl;dr

Comment: Related: [Does Christianity.StackExchange.com have issues with answer length?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1354/does-christianity-stackexchange-com-have-issues-with-answer-length)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on the question.

Certainly, we should not force a short answer, because it often *cannot* be enough. This is a Q&A site, not a forum. We should expect that people coming here want a **good answer**, not a short one. If someone doesn't read an answer because of its lengthiness ("tl;dr"), they probably weren't *really* interested in the first place.

We should neither force a long and descriptive answer, because sometimes one cannot be given without babbling. An example of a short answer that is more reasonable than a long answer would be: [What is the physical evidence for a local flood?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/802/what-is-the-archaeological-evidence-for-a-local-flood/803#803)